# Ошибка KeyError, при верном ключе

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Почему возникает ошибка, хотя ключ верный?

```
import json

class JobVacancyList:
    '''Сортировка вакансий'''
    def __init__(self):
        with open('All_jobs.json', "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        self.vacancies = []
        for vacancy in data:
            title = vacancy["Name"]
            salary_from = vacancy["Salary_from"]
            salary_to = vacancy["Salary_to"]
            description = vacancy["Requirement"]
            self.vacancies.append(Vacancy(title, salary_from, salary_to, description))

    def sort_by_salary_increase(self):
        self.vacancies = sorted(self.vacancies, key=lambda v: v.salary_from)

    def top_vacancies_by_salary(self, n=5):
        sorted_vacancies = sorted(self.vacancies, key=lambda v: v.salary_from, reverse=True)
        top_vacancies = sorted_vacancies[:n]
        for vacancy in top_vacancies:
            print(vacancy)



job_vacancies = JobVacancyList()
job_vacancies.sort_by_salary_increase()
job_vacancies.top_vacancies_by_salary(n=10)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ilapranicnikov/Documents/Job_Parser/utils/classes.py", line 60, in <module>
    job_vacancies = JobVacancyList()
  File "/Users/ilapranicnikov/Documents/Job_Parser/utils/classes.py", line 44, in __init__
    salary_from = vacancy["Salary_from"]
KeyError: 'Salary_from'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Фрагмент JSON файла:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a Python",
        "Salary_from": 200000,
        "Salary_to": 250000,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/78473911",
        "Requirement": "\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 <highlighttext>Python</highlighttext> (asyncio, aiohttp, pydantic, FastAPI). \u041e\u043f\u044b\u0442 \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u044b \u0441 \u0440\u0435\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u044f\u043c, \u0430\u043b\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u043c\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u0434\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0432\u044c\u044f\u0445 (\u0432\u0430\u0436\u043d\u043e!). \u041f\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043c \u043d\u0443\u0436\u0435\u043d \u041e\u041e\u041f. "
    },
    {
        "Name": "Python-\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a (Django, DRF)",
        "Salary_from": 60000,
        "Salary_to": 220000,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/70705466",
        "Requirement": "\u041e\u043f\u044b\u0442 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438 \u0441\u043b\u043e\u0436\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0432. \u041e\u0431\u044f\u0437\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043d \u043e\u043f\u044b\u0442 \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u044b \u0441 django 2.*, <highlighttext>python</highlighttext> 3.7, djangorestframework. \u0417\u043d\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 SQL (\u0432 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438, PostgreSQL) \u0438..."
    },
    {
        "Name": "Python \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a",
        "Salary_from": 100000,
        "Salary_to": 200000,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/77650733",
        "Requirement": "\u0418\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 git \u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u043e \u0431\u044b\u0442\u044c \u0435\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u043c. \u041e\u043f\u044b\u0442 <highlighttext>Python</highlighttext>/Django \u043e\u0442 \u0442\u0440\u0435\u0445 \u043b\u0435\u0442. \u0425\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448\u0435\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0440\u0435\u043b\u044f\u0446\u0438\u043e\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0441\u0443\u0431\u0434 (\u0443 \u043d\u0430\u0441 PostrgeSQL). "
    },
    {
        "Name": "Backend \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0438\u0441\u0442 Python / Python Backend Developer",
        "Salary_from": 50000,
        "Salary_to": 0,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/78542200",
        "Requirement": "\u0425\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448\u0435\u0435 \u0437\u043d\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f <highlighttext>Python</highlighttext>. \u0417\u043d\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 SQL (PostgreSQL) \u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0435\u043c \u0443\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043d\u0435. \u041d\u0430\u0432\u044b\u043a \u0441\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e\u044f\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0430 \u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438 \u0438 \u0433\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0439. "
    },
    {
        "Name": "\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a Python",
        "Salary_from": 90000,
        "Salary_to": 150000,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/77871173",
        "Requirement": "\u0425\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448\u0438\u0435 \u0437\u043d\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f <highlighttext>Python</highlighttext> 3.6+, Django, Django REST Framework. \u041d\u0430\u0432\u044b\u043a \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u044b \u0441 Git. \u0423\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u0447\u0443\u0436\u043e\u043c \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435. "
    },
    {
        "Name": "\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0438\u0441\u0442/Python-\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a",
        "Salary_from": 50000,
        "Salary_to": 70000,
        "Link": "https://hh.ru/vacancy/77901810",
        "Requirement": "\u0421\u043f\u043e\u0441\u043e\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0443\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0430\u043c\u0438. \u0421\u043f\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0430 \u0441 \u043e\u043f\u044b\u0442\u043e\u043c \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f <highlighttext>Python</highlighttext>. \u041d\u0430\u0432\u044b\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438 \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0438 \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0437 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432 \u2013 \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u044b, html..."
    }]
```

Comment: Если вылетает, значит ключа действительно нет. Оберните в try-except, выведите vacancy, на котором вылетает ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вместо строки

```
salary_from = vacancy["Salary_from"]
```

Использовать

```
salary_from = vacancy.get("Salary_from", 0)
```

В этом случае, если поле "Salary_from" не найдено в записи, будет использовано значение по умолчанию 0